# how to create a button using html and php

Tags: php, html

I have created two php codes one is for add product to cart and the other php code is to remove product from cart.However I was just wondering will I need to create a button using html near the product table so that users are able to add or remove the product from their basket.

```html
<?php
session_start();
 
// get the product id
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : "";
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : "";
$quantity = isset($_GET['quantity']) ? $_GET['quantity'] : "";
 
/*
 * check if the 'cart' session array was created
 * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
}
 
// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if(array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION['cart_items'])){
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=exists&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
 
// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $_SESSION['cart_items'][$id]=$name;
 
    // redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
    header('Location: products.php?action=added&id' . $id . '&name=' . $name);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Can you paste your code here?

Answer (score 0):

You provide just php code. If you want use it on frontend - you need to create link, form, ajax.

1. link

   `<a href="yourcode.php?id=ID&name=NAME&quantity=QUANTITY">`
2. form

   `<form action="yourcode.php">
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value="ID">
       <input type="hidden" name="name" value="NAME">
       <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
       <input type="submit" value="Add or Delete">
   </form>`
3. ajax (jquery). For ajax you need to return json response as {success: true, message: "Product has been added to the cart"} also you can use $.ajax instead $.get.

   `$.get('yourcode.php', {id: 'ID', name: 'NAME', quantity: 'QUANTITY'}, 
       function (response) {
           if (response.success && response.message) {
               alert(response.message);
           } else {
               alert('Something went wrong');
           }
       }
   );`